# How to create the directive necessary to use jquery maphilight in one of my partials in angularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

one of my partials has an image map that i would like to be able to highlight using maphilight and I dont understand how to create a directive that would properly implement this. I tried adding this directive in with the rest of my controllers but no luck.

```
var roomControllers = angular.module('roomControllers', []);
roomControllers.directive('mapHilight', function() {
return {

    link: function() {
    $('img[usemap]').maphilight();
    };
};
```

});

Here is the section of the partial that creates the image map

```
<div class="info" mapHilight>
  <script src="js/jquery.maphilights.js"></script>
  <img ng-src="images/housediagram.jpg" alt="Photo of thing" class="map" usemap="#houseMap" >

  <map name="houseMap" id="map" class="maphilight">
    <area name="office" shape="poly" coords="198,108,196,190,301,191,301,83,256,80" href="#/office"/>
    <area name="bathroom" shape="poly" coords="301,83,302,190,418,191,417,83" href="#/bathroom"/>
    <area name="bedroom" shape="poly" coords="419,83,417,192,560,191,560,109,494,80" href="#/bedroom"/>
  </map>
</div>
```

new to this so sorry if I am just making a dumb mistake. Thanks for the help